# There is a small white line in the edge of the screen. What must I do to repair it?

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair

Recently I came across seeing a small white patch in the right corner of my laptop screen. What must can I do? Will this spread across over time? Will this be covered by the warranty?

Brand: Acer Nitro-5

[image: Find the image here]

Comment: Your Acer Nitro-5 should be covered under a warranty.

Comment: It's the monitor.  You could try to change the Display orientation to Potrait (flipped) to see if it is the graphics card.  But it is the monitor.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Yeah, I guess so. But when I use jscreenfix.com/fix.html for about half an hour, the patch disappears and then reappears after about an hour which makes troubleshooting even more difficult.

Comment: You need to separate is it monitor or graphics card.  Flip orientation.  Just because it disappears does not mean it is not failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing on my desktop PC and it was the monitor. I replaced it. All well.

1. Try an external monitor and see if the white spot remains. Most likely not.
2. Will it spread? We cannot say with any clarity.
3. Is it covered under warranty?  Check your purchase date and receipt.

To repair:  Replace the display. Take it to a local shop or send it back under warranty.

Finally:  if you can live with the small spot, just leave it for the time being, as there is no practical way to repair a display panel

Comment: What is the reason for it to happen?

Comment: Display may have a hardware error inside the display. It is just an electronic part.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to repair it without a replacement?

Comment: No, I do not think so. You need to get the display replaced.

Comment: when I use https://www.jscreenfix.com/fix.html for about half an hour, the patch disappears and then reappears after about an hour. Why is that? Do you still think it needs replacement?

Comment: It is a hardware issue and up to whether you wish to accommodate the white line or replace the screen as you choose do do. It is impossible to fix a defective display panel.